# Include folders into Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, include, directory

I know, this is a noob-question. Sorry about this, but how can I include a folders into my Netbeans, so that they are shown on the left sidebar. I was not able to figure out how it works and this question is not asked, yet.
thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders shown on the left side, are the real folders of the projects that you have opened.

If you want to add some folders, you only have to do is create or open a project and his folder will be shown.

Comment: Well, if i open a typicall html-file with netbeans it works fine. But there are no other folders on the left sidebar nor i can click the other css/html/js-files. I just changed from notepad to netbeans cause of the functionality, but this annoys me a bit. EDIT: Well, i can open another file, but i have to go into my explorer to open it.

Comment: Then, why you don't create a new projecte with these files?

Comment: Cause the files are already created. I want them to copy as a project in netbeans.

Comment: When you create a new Netbeans project, you have several options, and one of those are Create a New Project with Existing Sources. It isn't useful for you?

Comment: Finally i got it! Thanks for your help. Have a nice weekend!